# SSRS The textrun uses a First aggregate in an outer aggregate (Different datasets)

Tags: dataset, ssrs-2008

Ok, I'm working on a multi-data report that merges data from many servers.
dataset1 = One of six datasets with the data I need.

ds_BusinessDays = A calendar table dataset with Specific dates and numbers that change every day/week/month.

I'm trying to use a SWITCH where MonthName(Date) from dataset1 = MonthName(Date2) from ds_BusinessDays. Then Sum the total count.

I have successfully used similar cross dataset calculations like 
SUM(SWITCH when Data = "Product" then 1) / SUM(businessdaysinmonth, "ds_BusinessDays")
This was to get the Average. works like a charm.

```
=SUM(
    SWITCH(Fields!Requested_Month.Value = MonthName(Month(First(Fields!PreviousBusinessDate.Value, "ds_BusinessDays")))
    ,1)
)
```

All Fields in ds_BusinessDays dataset are 1 entry results.  Example, "PreviousBusinessDay" = "6/21/2019".  So I want my code to do something like this. 
When MonthName(Date) form dataset1 = MonthName(PreviousBusinessDate) from ds_BusinessDays then 1.  Sum all of that up to get my a total for that month.
The problem is that FIRST and SUM are the only fields available to me when using fields from another dataset. They can't be used in an Aggregate within an Aggregate.

Is there a substitute that I can use for First in First(Fields!PreviousBusinessDate.Value, "ds_BusinessDays")?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a `SWITCH` when you only have a single conditional?  I think an `IIF` would be much easier to read.  Also, if `ds_BusinessDays.PreviousBusinessDate` is a single entry, why do you even need `FIRST`?  There should only be one result.  If you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do, this expression should do it.

```
= SUM(IIF(Fields!Requested_Month.Value = MonthName(Month(Fields!PreviousBusinessDate.Value, "ds_BusinessDays")), 1, 0))
```

To add additional detail, a `SWITCH` is best used for more than 2 conditional statements.  If you're only trying to compare two fields, you can just use a simple `IIF`.  An example of when `SWITCH` is necessary:

```
 =SUM(SWITCH(Fields!Date.Value = Fields!Today.Value, 1,
             Fields!Date.Value = Fields!Yesterday.Value, 2,
             Fields!Date.Value = Fields!Tomorrow.Value, 3,
             true, 0))
```

This expression would check `Date` against three different fields and return a different count for each, ending with an always true condition that catches everything else.  Your expression doesn't need a `SWITCH`.

Comment: Sorry for the simplified explanation.  The SWITCH is part of a longer series, just this section was the part I was having problems with.

Also, I wasn't aware the SUM/FIRST weren't required. I had tried removing them before and it didn't work. I'll try it again. There are quite a few calculations using this so it will be a while.

Comment: Well if I'm reading it right, you should only have one value for `PreviousBusinessDate`.  Unless that field returns multiple values, you shouldn't need `FIRST`.

Comment: I tried using 
'=SUM(SWITCH(Fields!Requested_Month.Value = MonthName(Month(Fields!PreviousBusinessDate.Value, "ds_BusinessDays"))
,1)
)'
This is the error I got. 
The Value expression for the text box 'Textbox 1032' refers to the fiel 'Previous Business Date'. Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggredate, the specified dataset scope. Letter in the name of the fields must of the correct case. 

FYI, the spelling and case are correct.

Comment: Looks like you might need a `Lookup` function.  Is there any field in common between the two datasets?  If so, `LOOKUP(Fields!Dataset1Common.Value, Fields!Dataset2Common.Value, Fields!FieldToLookup.Value, "DatasetToLookup")`

Comment: No, there is nothing in common from the Data table we get from our client and the Calendar in business days table.  The date comes in as month name and the Calendar table is actual dates being used, then converted. This Calendar table is updated each evening through a job and outside of my control. Same with the client table.   I guess i'll just create a dummy field with a fake "Date" converted from DateName.  was trying to avoid this but I guess I'll have too.